# How to compare placeholders handlebars with #compare

Tags: javascript, html, select, compare, handlebars.js

I'm having a bad time trying to compare an item with another with Handlebars. 
As you can see from the code below, I just want to check if the `course_id` is the same as requested (`courseID = req.query.course_id`), so in my select the item selected would be the one that has been asked with a query.

However, I cannot find any solution to make the compare work (I installed handlebars helpers) with another placeholder. For instance, the code work if I replace `courseID` with `"5ae0aebc8ab041016c9e08db"` ( `"5ae0aebc8ab041016c9e08db"` being the `course_id` queried in the url).

Do you know any mean to make it work please ?

```
                <form id= "course_id" action="" method='get'>
            <select id="course_id" name="course_id" onChange="document.getElementById('course_id').submit()">
                {{#each courses}}
                    <option value="{{this._id}}" {{#compare this._id "==" courseID }}selected="selected"{{/compare}} >{{this.name}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: You're making it difficult for someone who wants to help you by not including your data structure. Likely it's a scope issue and you need to do something like `../courseID`. See: http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths

Answer (score 0):

You can use handlebars custom helper functions. Just add to your express app this:

```
/* equals helper */
hbs.registerHelper('ifEquals', function (v1, v2, options) {
    if (v1 === v2) return options.fn(this);
    return options.inverse(this);
});

/* not equals helper */
hbs.registerHelper('ifNotEquals', function (v1, v2, options) {
    if (v1 !== v2) return options.fn(this);
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And then in your HTML:

```
{{#each courses}}
    <option value="{{this._id}}" {{#ifEquals this._id courseID }}selected="selected"{{/ifEquals}}>{{this.name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```